# How can I extract rows from a database with python? I have a csv file with a list of 1000 ID's and I only want the rows that match these

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pyodbc

Csv: ID, 100, 200, 300,...9900, 10000

SQL Columns:

```
ID Name
100 Henry
101 John
200 Eric
300 Lucy
```

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import csv

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};''SERVER=my_server;''Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID in ' + tuple([100, 200, 300]), cnxn)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# create csv_dataframe
csv_dateframe = pd.read_csv(r"file_path")

# create sql_dataframe
sql_dateframe = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)

# innerjoin
pd.merge(csv_dataframe,sql_dataframe,on="ID")
```